# Changing Aurelia app's index page

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am working with an Aurelia app that should start at a different page than `index.html`, but I cannot find where to change that.

Where in an Aurelia app can you set which landing page to use?

Comment: Take a look at the Aurelia tutorial here and see how they setup their start page: https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-todo-app#setup

Comment: Sometimes yhe first page comes from the backend , hope that is not the case?

Comment: You can check in network console , what content you are getting when you hit localhost

Comment: can you share the url you are trying to access?

Answer (score 3):

This is misunderstanding. `index.html` page is the default landing page set by web server, not Aurelia. E.g. if you try to get the url e.g.`https://stackoverflow.com` the web server will give `index.html` by default. You need to change it in web server.

e.g. using Apache web server directive `DirectoryIndex myindex.html`

> From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html:
>
> The `DirectoryIndex` directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of the directory name.

When using development server of Aurelia (default webpack-dev-server configured by aurelia-cli), the `index.ejs` compiles to `index.html`. You may need to change configuration of HtmlWebpackPlugin in `webpack.config.js` in order to change generated file from `index.html` to some other name:

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'index.ejs',
  filename: 'myindex.html',
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CLI, there is not an easy way to do this. The CLI is mostly for basic use cases, and if you're trying to do something fancy, you're going to have to learn a bit more about JavaScript tooling.

You can still do it and here's how:

Open **aurelia_project/tasks/run.js** and make sure the `server` property of the argument to the `browserSync` function has the `index` property pointing at the index file you want to use, like this:

```
let serve = gulp.series(
  build,
  done => {
    browserSync({
      online: false,
      open: false,
      port: 9000,
      logLevel: 'silent',
      server: {
        index: 'my-special-index.html', // Make sure you have this line in there.
        baseDir: [project.platform.baseDir],
        middleware: [historyApiFallback(), function(req, res, next) {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          next();
        }]
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty easy way, why would you say there's _no easy way to do this_?

Comment: I've just tried this method, but whenever I visit `localhost:9000` it still points to the `index.html` file

Comment: That seems easy but it didn't work. If you want it to work, it's not so easy. There's a way to get it done using this method, but like I said, you can't just copy paste my answer, you gotta pay attention to what is being logged in your console, make sure that you're modifying the correct configuration, etc. It's not easy.